# Unable to put a UIImageView inside SKScene's view

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, sprite-kit

I need to show a gif image and I have tried `SKSpriteNote` but it has no gif support. So I want to use `UIImageView` instead.

in MyScene.m init method:

```
#import "UIImage+animatedGIF.h"

CGSize size = CGSizeMake(144, 82);

//create a uiview on top of skview
self.demoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2 - size.width / 2, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2 - size.height / 2, size.width, size.height)];

[self.view addSubview:self.demoView];

//set the image to be the gif (I use a category from github)
self.demoView.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Helper pathInBundleWithFileName:[self demoFileNameWithStep:step]]]];
[self.demoView startAnimating];
```

It's not about the gif image, because even if I try static png image, the image view is not shown.

I have tried this as well but it's not working either:

```
    [self.view.superview addSubview:self.demoView];
    [self.view.superview bringSubviewToFront:self.demoView];
```

Comment: image frame outside the screen perhaps?

Comment: the image is supposed to be in the center of skview. i don't see any miscalculation

Comment: check that self.view is non-nil. If this code is in init it will be nil.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D wow I didn't know that. it is nil. but where should I put it? i can't find methods similar to viewDidAppear or onEnter (like cocos2d)

Comment: well, after you called presentScene with the scene you will receive a message on the scene named didMoveToView. That's where you can run this code, and self.view will be non-nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move code that refers to `self.view` to the SKScene method [didMoveToView:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKScene/didMoveToView%3a). Before that (ie in init) the `self.view` reference will be nil because the scene hasn't been presented on a view yet.